# conditionally redirecting users page on login (React)

Tags: node.js, reactjs, react-router-dom

I have created a login form which is interacting with my client (in react ) and express/mssql npm middle which then speaks to my database. My question is fairly simple.

The all the backend stuff is done all I would want to know is how would I redirect my user. Where console . log success is within the code below is where I would like to put it .

I have tried this.state.history push and the  but these do not seem to be working. How would I simply redirect my user from

```
.then(data => {
          console.log("Success:", data);
          // <Redirect to="/somewhere/else" />;
        })
```

Full code of this handle submit just in case it helps anyone.

```
 handleSubmit(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    if (this.state.email.length < 8 || this.state.password.length < 8) {
      alert(`please enter the form correctly `);
    } else {
      const data = { email: this.state.email, password: this.state.password };

      fetch("/login", {
        method: "POST", // or 'PUT'
        headers: {
          Accept: "application/json, text/plain, */*",
          "Content-Type": "application/json"
        },
        body: JSON.stringify(data)
      })
        // .then(response => response.json())
        .then(data => {
          console.log("Success:", data);
          // <Redirect to="/somewhere/else" />;
        })

        .catch(error => {
          console.error("Error:", error);
        });
    }
  }
  catch(e) {
    console.log(e);
  }
```

Comment: ```window.location.href = '/somewhere/else'```?

Comment: thanks ! Put this as an answer and ill mark it as the answer

Comment: Also you can use this: https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/master/packages/react-router/docs/api/Redirect.md

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `window.location.href` to redirect your users, but the best option would be to use `Redirect`.

```
.then(data => {
  console.log("Success:", data);
   // in here set value to true
   // this.setState({ redirect | isLoggedIn: true})
   // or setLoggedIn(true)
  // <Redirect to="/somewhere/else" />;
 })
```

Then in your render, check if the value is true, then redirect

```
const App = () => {
  return (
    <>
     {isLoggedIn
       ? <Redirect to="/somewhere/else" />
       : <SomePage />
     }
    </>
  )
}
```